# Combine output of 2 select statements and put in a single column temporary table in stored procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I tried multiple posts on StackOverflow, but none found for my specific case. So asking a question: I am using a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 and creating a temporary table with only a single column `plan_year` as shown here:

```
DECLARE @tbl_PlanYears TABLE
(
    plan_year VARCHAR(4)
);
```

Now I have an array of strings [years] `planYears` which I want to store into this table variable. Also, I want to store current year in this column.

I'm using this code for the insert:

```
INSERT INTO @tbl_PlanYears
    SELECT string FROM udf_SplitString (@planYears,',')
    UNION
    SELECT YEAR(GETDATE());
```

Strings from `planYears` are stored correctly. But how to store current year value as well in that same column without replacing previous years?

Comment: `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION` will do?

Answer (score 0):

What about `UNION ALL` instead of `UNION`

```
INSERT @tbl_PlanYears
SELECT string FROM udf_SplitString (@planYears,',')
UNION ALL
SELECT YEAR(getdate());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be consistent about the types.  If you want the current year to be *duplicated* if it is present in the string as well, then use `UNION ALL`:

```
INSERT @tbl_PlanYears (plan_year)
    SELECT string FROM udf_SplitString(@planYears, ',')
    UNION ALL
    SELECT DATEPART(YEAR, getdate());
```

`UNION` removes duplicates.